# 2 Arrays Working as 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, radio-button

I have two separate radio button arrays that should behave as if they are one.  Currently, I have it only working one way. I have a [YouTube video showing my problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlvzgu3pJ8A).

I have two mutually exclusive arrays that I want them working together as one array to the user. E.g., If one radio button is checked" in one array, I do not want the other array's radio button checked, but unchecked. JavaScript should deselect the radio button in the other array, making the functionality to look like the user is working with one set of radio buttons. The two separate radio arrays have different name=pair values.

**YouTube Video Showing Problem**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlvzgu3pJ8A

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <style>
        body{font-family:sans-serif, arial;}
        th{text-align:left;}
        h3,h4{margin-top:.15em; padding:0;}
    </style>
    <script>
        function monthlyPlan(){
        for(var i=0; i<document.deliveryForm.monthly.length;++i)
            {
            if(document.deliveryForm.monthly[i].checked== true )
                document.deliveryForm.weekly.checked = false;    
            }
        }
        function weeklyPlan(){
        for(var i=0; i<document.deliveryForm.weekly.length;++i)
            {
            if(document.deliveryForm.weekly[i].checked == true)
                document.deliveryForm.monthly.checked = false;    
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="deliveryForm" action="FormProcessor.html" method="get">
            <h3>Delivery Rates</h3>
            <h4>Allow users to select their desired delivery option.</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>Bill weekly or monthly</li>
                    <li>Devlivered Mon-Sat or Everyday</li>
                </ul>
            <p>
                <strong>Billed continuously $3.50 by the Month?</strong>
                <input type="radio" name="monthly" value="yes" onclick="monthlyPlan();" />  Yes    
            </p>
            <strong>Billed by a Weekly Plan?</strong>
            <table border=1 cellpadding=6>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>4 weeks</th>
                    <th>13 weeks</th>
                    <th>26 weeks</th>
                    <th>52 weeks</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Devlivered Mon-Sat</th>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="weekly" value="12.60" onclick="weeklyPlan();" />12.60</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="weekly" value="40.95" onclick="weeklyPlan();" />40.95</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="weekly" value="81.90" onclick="weeklyPlan();" />81.90</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="weekly" value="156.00" onclick="weeklyPlan();" />156.00</td>
                </tr>
                    <th>Devlivered Everyday</th>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="weekly" value="13.56" onclick="weeklyPlan();" />13.56</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="weekly" value="44.07" onclick="weeklyPlan();" />44.07</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="weekly" value="88.14" onclick="weeklyPlan();" />88.14</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="weekly" value="159.74" onclick="weeklyPlan();" />159.74</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: UI-wise, a radio button group *must* have one item selected, it should not be possible to unselect it once an option has been chosen. It's bad enough that it is possible to have an unchecked default state; it's even worse that it's technically possible to uncheck it again. Don't do this. If two groups of radio buttons should behave as one, **make them one radio button group.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    function monthlyPlan() {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.deliveryForm.weekly.length; ++i) {
            document.deliveryForm.weekly[i].checked = false;
        }
    }

    function weeklyPlan() {
        document.deliveryForm.monthly.checked = false;
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DpbMB/

You don't need to test whether the radio that was just clicked is checked, because for radio buttons you know they *will* be checked when the click event occurs (there's no way to uncheck them by clicking except by clicking on another in the group, and then it is the other that gets the event).

When the monthly radio button is clicked, loop over all of the weekly radio buttons and set them to not be checked. When any weekly radio is clicked simply uncheck the monthly one.

The array-style access is only applicable when there is more than one element with the same name, so to access the monthly button don't use `[i]`.

It seems to me though that it would be easier to just make the monthly button part of the same group, and give it an appropriate value that you can test server-side.

Comment: Thank you!  Ok...so when I click on the monthly radio, loop through the weekly array and set any checked to false. That's very clear.  
And since Monthly has only one button, I don't need to write monthly[0], or loop through an array; I can't just use the name=value pair in that case. Thanks again

Comment: You had `monthly[i]` trying to access `monthly` as an array-like object when it isn't, and you had `weekly.checked` trying to access `weekly` as a non-array-like object it it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for your monthlyPlan() function:

```
    function monthlyPlan(){
    /*for(var i=0; i<document.deliveryForm.monthly.length;++i)
        {
        if(document.deliveryForm.monthly.checked== true )
            document.deliveryForm.weekly.checked = false;    
        }
    */
        alert(document.deliveryForm.monthly.length);    // will say undefined
        if (document.deliveryForm.monthly.checked)
        {
            for (var k = 0; k < document.deliveryForm.weekly.length; ++k)
            {
                document.deliveryForm.weekly[k].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

It appears that when you only have one radio button in the group, the DOM doesn't treat it as an array.

EDIT: Actually, nnnnnn's answer is better. No point keeping the redundant if statements.

Comment: >> It appears that when you only have one radio button in the group, the DOM doesn't treat it as an array >>
I was surprised about that. Appears it's just read as a single Name=value pair instead. :)

Comment: BTW. Why didn't my original code work for setting the weekly arrays to non checked?